# Can I highlight Lisp like this?

Tags: spacemacs, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Spacemacs, and I REALLY love how Dr. Racket background highlights parentheses as you move around.

I'm wondering if I can do this in Emacs instead of this God forsaken "rainbow delimiters" that give me a headache.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually want to change the selected answer to myself after doing a lot more research. The given answer above is close, but not quite. It highlights the entire line which I don't want (for example it won't highlight the `(circle 10)` inside `(visalign (circle 10) (circle 20))`.

For this, I ended up using this package:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(
  (highlight-sexp :location (recipe :fetcher github :repo "daimrod/highlight-sexp"))
  )
```

And my config in `user-config`:

```
(setq hl-sexp-foreground-color nil)
(setq hl-sexp-background-color "#333")
```

If that doesn't work for you, I found various `sexp` highlight packages. They're all slightly different. For example one includes the parens, another doesn't. But for the most part they all do the same thing.

- https://github.com/daimrod/highlight-sexp
- https://github.com/emacsmirror/hl-sexp
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSexps (code [here](http://david.rysdam.org/src/emacs/highlight-sexps.el))

Comment: FWIW, `show-paren-mode` with `show-paren-style` set to `'expression` works fine for me, e.g. `(circle 10)` is also highlighted.

Comment: show-paren-style works for me when the cursor is over one of the parens enclosing an expression, this updated answer involving highlight-sexp highlights the whole expression when the cursor is anywhere in the expression.

Answer (score 13):

With `show-paren-mode` you can highlight the whole expression. You need to have the following code in your init file. You can try different style and choose what you like to highlight.

```el
(show-paren-mode t) ;; enable show paren mode

(setq show-paren-style 'expression) ;; highlight whole expression
```

Refer : http://emacs-fu.blogspot.in/2009/01/balancing-your-parentheses.html

Comment: If spacemacs isn't autocompleting the symbol `'expression` does that mean its unavailable? It doesn't seem to be working. I noticed it autocompletes `show-paren-style` but not the value.

Comment: I got it working, I had to add both lines. Do you know how I can make it change the background color rather than changing the text color? Thanks!

Comment: Tallboy: The link that Hariharan provided gave you that information.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry I must have missed that.

Comment: @Tallboy Emacs completion does not consider all interned symbols, only bound ones. Clearly `expression` is an arbitrary, unbound symbol in this case. If `show-paren-style` hadn't previously been defined as a variable, you wouldn't be able to complete it either.